# Split string with enclosed strings and space

Tags: java, split

I try to split the with the '''String.split''' but I cannot keep the content in double quote mark.
here is my code

```
    import java.util.*;


    public class L8_Task2{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        ArrayList<String> arr_list = new ArrayList<String>();
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("\nEnter the arguments:");
        String s = scan.nextLine();
        arr_list = splitstring(s);
        for(String str: arr_list){
            System.out.println(str);
        }
        
    }
    
    public static ArrayList<String> splitstring(String s){
        ArrayList<String> arr_list = new ArrayList<String>();
        String[] str_arr=s.split("\\s|\"");
        
        for(String str: str_arr){
            arr_list.add(str);
        }
        
        return arr_list;
    }


}
```

But the output should be like this

```
a 
friend
good morning 
good afternoon
b
```

I cannot keep the content in double quote in a same line
I need help please

Answer (score 0):

you can format the output and add the quote mark to each string, after the split like this:

```
for(String str: arr_list){
        System.out.println(String.format("\"%s\"", str));
}
```